# Fix unquoted PHP array keys

Tags: php, arrays, constants, find-replace

*Or rather "Fix unquoted strings used as PHP array keys" but that was a bit long for a title.*

I have inherited a quite large codebase where arrays are written like this:

```
$array[id] = 0;
$array[value] = "test"
```

While this code actually works, it's throwing a lot of `Use of undefined constant` notices, so those lines really need to become:

```
$array['id'] = 0;
$array['value'] = "test"
```

We are talking about hundreds of thousands lines of codes spread into couple of thousand files.

There are also cases like this:

```
$_SESSION[user_information][access_bit][ACCESS_NULL] = 1;
```

Where `user_information` and `access_bit` are meant to be strings and `ACCESS_NULL` is a defined constant. The good thing is that constants are only defined in uppercase.

And to make things more interesting we also have javascript in the same php files, where code like `array[id] = 0;` is perfectly fine.

I want to clean up this mess efficiently and wrap all those undefined constants in single quotes, but I'm not sure a simple find/replace (even with a regular expression) will do it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Even if you use a tokenizer/parser-based tool to fix that, you won't avoid manual proofchecking. So you might as well go for a regex fix, which can be made relatively context-sensitive with ease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be easier than I thought.

```
function fix_unquoted_array_keys($filename){
    if(!is_file($filename)){
        return "File not found!";
    }
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $content = preg_replace('/^!|\$([a-zA-Z_]+)\[([a-z_]+)\]/','\$$1[\'$2\']',$content);
    $content = preg_replace('/\]\[([a-z_]+)\]/','][\'$1\']',$content);
    file_put_contents($filename,$content);

    // Check the file just in case we break something.
    @exec("php -l ".$filename." 2>&1",$syntax);
    if($syntax[0] && strpos($syntax[0],"No syntax errors") === false){
        return $syntax[0];
    }

    return "OK";
}
```

The first `preg_replace` replaces all simple arrays like `$user[id]` to `$user['id']`. It leaves multidimensional arrays like `$user[data][id]` to `$user['data'][id]`. I'm deliberately not matching uppercase keys, because they are most probably defined constants.

The second `preg_replace` works on all subsequent keys by simply matching the closing bracket of the previous key.

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it seems that it did the job. I'm now checking diffs for the last hour and I can't find a single place where this has failed.

P.S. the [PHP tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) fails on this task, because it also seems to be converting the undefined constant as a strings and they are tokenized as `T_STRING`.

Comment: You need to consider that there can be numbers in the var name too (like $row2[xxxx]), but still, this works really nice. For use in editors (like atom and sublime) you can use `^!|\$([a-zA-Z_]+)\[([a-z_]+)\]` and `$$$1["$2"]`. You sir saved my internet today.

Comment: Using this pretty hack on the idle phpstorm at least, required to escape the $ on the replace. Instead of  $$$1["$2"]  I have to use: \$$1['$2']. Thanks, I had the same problem as @Jacket and this really save my day!

Comment: But this does not match something like `$myAr[firstone][second2]`. Also, constant calls are ignored (with the completely uppercase convention). It would also replace the constants.

Answer (score 1):

I've built upon @Jacket's answer to address the following:

- Use the PHP "official" regex for finding variables
- Allow capital letters at the beginning of an array key name
- Allow numbers in the array key name as long as it doesn't start with a number
- Performs the searching and replacing only in PHP blocks (i.e. excluding HTML or XML in the same file)
- Adds curly brackets (`{}`) around these kinds of variables in double-quoted strings

There are some things it doesn't do:

- Recognition of constants as array key names (it's still assumed that all constants are all uppercase)
- Handle cases where array key names have uppercase letters in the 2nd or later position (e.g. `$var[LineBreak]` wouldn't be handled because of the uppercase `B`)
- Add curly brackets around variable/array references in comments (e.g. `// this is "my comment with $var[name]"` would only be changed to `// this is "my comment with $var['name']"`)

Here is my code:

```php
function get_php_blocks($content) {
    $blocks = [];
    $len = strlen($content);
    $cursor = 0;

    do {
        $stepper = '';
        $try_again = false;

        do {
            // find the block
            $matches = [];
            if ($found = preg_match('/(<\?(?:=|php\s).+?'.$stepper.'(?:\?>|$))/ms', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $cursor)) {
                // make sure the end is valid
                $tokens = @token_get_all($matches[0][0]);
                $last = array_pop($tokens);
                $try_again = // try again if...
                    ($matches[0][1] + strlen($matches[0][0])) < $len // we're not at the end of the string
                    && (
                        !is_array($last) // it's not a single character
                        || $last[0] !== T_CLOSE_TAG // it's not a close tag
                    );
            } else {
                $try_again = false;
            }

            if ($try_again) {
                // add to the stepper
                $stepper .= '\?>.+?';
            } elseif ($found) {
                // record the block
                $blocks[] = $matches[0][0];

                // update the offset
                $cursor = $matches[0][1] + strlen($matches[0][0]); // offset + length
            } else {
                // there's no more php to search for
                $cursor = $len;
            }
        } while ($try_again);

    } while ($cursor < $len);

    return $blocks;
}

function fix_unquoted_array_keys($content) {
    // get all php blocks
    $blocks = get_php_blocks($content);
    foreach ($blocks as $block) {
        // do replacements for the first index level
        $orig_block = $block;
        $block = preg_replace('/^!|\$([a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*)\[([a-zA-Z_][a-z0-9_]+)\]/','\$$1[\'$2\']', $block, -1, $c1);
        $count = $c1;

        // do replacements for subsequent index levels
        $block = preg_replace('/\]\[([a-zA-Z_][a-z0-9_]+)\]/', '][\'$1\']', $block, -1, $c2);
        $count += $c2;

        // find double-quoted strings
        if ($count > 0) {
            $block = preg_replace_callback('/\/\*.*?\*\/(*SKIP)^|\/\/.*?$(*SKIP)^|\'(?>\\\\?.)*?\'(*SKIP)^|"(?>\\\\?.)*?"/ms', function ($matches) {
                // add brakets to array key references in the string
                return preg_replace('/(?<![{\\\\])(\$\w+(?:\[\'\w+\'\]){1,})/', '{$1}', $matches[0]);
            }, $block);
        }

        // update it
        $content = str_replace($orig_block, $block, $content);
    }

    return $content;
}

function fix_file($filename) {
    // get file
    if (!is_file($filename)) {
        return "Not a valid file!";
    }
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);

    // do the work
    try {
        $content = fix_unquoted_array_keys($content);
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    // put it back
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);

    // check the file just in case we broke something
    @exec("php -l ".$filename." 2>&1", $syntax);
    if ($syntax[0] && strpos($syntax[0], "No syntax errors") === false) {
        return $syntax[0];
    }

    return "OK";
}
```

To use this solution, call `fix_file()` and pass in the relative or absolute filename of the file to process.

I've used this solution in a script I wrote to be used on the command line, and adds reporting and handling recursive file paths:
https://gist.github.com/inventor96/927239a939c9c3d14447446a86a2f7b1